# Openssh programatic MD5 hash digest not matching the shell command output

Tags: c++, openssl, md5

I'm experimenting with MD5 hashes using the openssl library.  When I run the code below:

```
std::string test("123");    // salt
test.append("TestPhrase");  // password
unsigned char buffer[test.size()];
strcpy((char *)buffer, test.c_str());
unsigned char digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
MD5_CTX(ctx);
MD5_Init(&ctx);
MD5_Update(&ctx, buffer, test.size());
for(int i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i)
{
  printf("%02x", digest[i]);
}
  putchar('\n');
```

I'm consistently getting a hash value of:

```
ad9c231a6c45cccecc3b558545e7fd75
```

I used the Openssl documentation as a reference and looked around to see how others are doing it.  It certainly is not the cleanest code, but I don't believe this is incorrect.  However, when I try to run the openssl command, which uses the same library and what I thought was the same hashing function I get a completely different value:

```
openssl passwd -quiet -salt "123" -1 "TestPhrase"

$1$123$PWLKL9JcywaTF.UrzC7ov/
```

I have also tried the Apache variant algorithm -apr1 which also generates a non-matching hash.  I'm assuming it must be the way I'm displaying the bits to the screen, but this seems to be how every post I have found does it.  What am I missing?

Comment: I suggest a review of [the MD5 crypt BSD algorithm.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#MD5-based_scheme) which is the one you're trying to emulate. It is **much** more complicated than a simple concat+hash. There is also a secondary and tertiary hash step, then an iteration loop. Get the openssl source tree. in the apps folder you'll find passwd.c, at or around line 294 is the `md5crypt` function, which details exactly how their implementation of the BSD MD5 algorithm 1 is formed. It is *far* more complicated than you've been led to believe (and considered insecure by today's bar)

Comment: Will do. But just to be clear, I am comparing to the command line listed below. Not necessarily the password algorithm.  Are they this same?

Comment: `openssl passwd -quiet -salt "123" -1 "TestPhrase"`  The `-1` is the instruction to use the MD5 crypt BSD algorithm 1 I linked. Therefore, the command you're giving executes the aforementioned code I mentioned in command-line openssl. If the goal is to get a match to what `openssl passwd -quiet -salt "123" -1 "TestPhrase"` is doing, that's the way you're going to have to do it. The algorithm is public (sorta), but you have a distinct advantage in not only seeing the algorithm, but the actual source from the environment you're trying to match.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `openssl passwd` says for the `-1` option: *Use the MD5 based BSD password algorithm 1*. That is not the same thing as *Use MD5*, what you are doing. Just taking the md5 would result in passwords that are fairly easy to crack.

You can glance at the [md5crypt function](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/52c587d60be67c337364b830dd3fdc15404a2f04/apps/passwd.c#L311) implementation in the openssl passwd tool to see that the actual process is much more involved. For example it includes [a loop](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/52c587d60be67c337364b830dd3fdc15404a2f04/apps/passwd.c#L412) that repeetitively (1000x) invokes `EVP_DigestUpdate()`

It is surprisingly hard to find a proper description of that MD5 based BSD password algorithm 1, but this blog post does a good job: [Password hashing with MD5-crypt in relation to MD5](https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=32)

---

If you do want to reproduce your current result with an OpenSSL tool, you could use `dgst` like this:

```
$ printf 123TestPhrase | openssl dgst -md5   
ad9c231a6c45cccecc3b558545e7fd75
```

Answer (score 0):

`ad9c231a6c45cccecc3b558545e7fd75`

is just

`PWLKL9JcywaTF.UrzC7ov/`

, but in Hexadecimal instead of Base 64.

Comment: That's interesting, because a bas64 encoding of the octet stream `ad9c231a6c45cccecc3b558545e7fd75` is actually `rZwjGmxFzM7MO1WFRef9dQ==` , so I'm curious what encoder you're using when you make your claim.

Comment: Yep.  That’s what I got as well.